How to set up Azure MSAL for my Next Js App using App Router
I am working on a react app which uses App Router and runs on Next.js v 14.1.0 . Next.js App Router using app folder and containes layout.tsx as wrapper for react app.
I wanted to do Single Sign on SSO for my app using Azure MSAL ( link here ). But With App router and next.js combination., I did not find any article which explains complete configuration of MSAL-React with Next.js app.
Wondering anyone could suggest article which has clear guidelines on solution.
I have setup the configuration., it is redirecting to Microsoft page., after providing id and password., it is redirecting back to UnauthenticatedTemplate. I see accounts array is empty.
But my credentials are available in Azure AD. Using same., iam logging into my other applications.
Does next.js and App Router in my React app requires different configuration?
Below is my current configuration in layout.tsx.


"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./globals.css";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { AppStore, makeStore, persistor } from "@/lib/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { msalConfig } from "@/lib/Msal";
import { EventType, PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import {
  AuthenticatedTemplate,
  MsalProvider,
  UnauthenticatedTemplate,
  useIsAuthenticated,
} from "@azure/msal-react";
import Home from "./page";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  console.log("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);

  msalInstance.initialize().then(() => {
    const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
    }

    msalInstance.addEventCallback((event) => {
      if (
        event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS &&
        event.payload &&
        "account" in event.payload &&
        event.payload.account
      ) {
        const account = event.payload.account;
        msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current.__persistor}>
            <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                  <Home />
                </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <AuthenticatedTemplate>{children}</AuthenticatedTemplate>
              </Box>
            </MsalProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



This is my Msal.ts


import {
  Configuration,
  LogLevel,
} from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID || "default-client-id", // Azure AD client id
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`, // zure AD tenant id
    redirectUri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_REDIRECT_URL, // app redirect URL
    postLogoutRedirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/", // app logout URL
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // If you are having issues on IE11, you may need to set this to true
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
        }
      },
      logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
    },
  },
};

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["User.Read"],
};

export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
};



This is my login method:


import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from "@/lib/Msal";
const { instance } = useMsal();
const handleLoginClick = async () => {
  instance
    .loginRedirect(loginRequest)
    .catch((err) => console.error("login failed", err));
};



My Layout.tsx acts as wrapper for my app. It handles all Authenticated and Unauthenticated pages.
This is the log I see.


: @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:initializeEnd
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectStart
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:loginFailure
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-browser@3.10.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectEnd
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress from startup to handleRedirect
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress from startup to handleRedirect
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress from handleRedirect to none
Msal.ts:36 : @azure/msal-react@2.0.12 : Info - MsalProvider - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress from handleRedirect to none




Can you share your GitHub repo? or else complete the code?

@DasariKamali I have updated question with complete configuration. Hope this suffice

Can you share the screen shot of the error?

Have you added the output URL http://localhost:3000/ to the Azure AD app in Authentication like this.

@DasariKamali Yes I did... I added localhost:3000/dashboard since That is where I should be redirecting to post Authentication.... subject to environments., i added redirects URLs....
also., I updated error logs in question. I see msal:loginFailure event triggered.

@Seeker Do you know how to do the same if you want to trigger login automatically? using useMsalAuthentication in layout doesnt seem to work.

@CodingSlayer not sure exactly., what you are referring to for login automatically. Perhaps refer following link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router/78326638#78326638 ). It has step by step guide of Azure single Sign On

I tried the code below for Single Sign-on with a Next.js App using App Router, and successfully logged in and logged out.
Code :
Msal.ts :
import { Configuration, LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '<client_ID>' || '',
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/' || '',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/' || '',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
        }
      },
      logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
    },
  },
};
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ['User.Read'],
};
export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
};

Layout.tsx :
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useIsAuthenticated } from '@azure/msal-react';

const Layout: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  return (
    <div>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Layout;

_app.tsx :
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from '../lib/Msal';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
};
export default MyApp;

index.tsx :
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { loginRequest } from '../lib/Msal';

const Home = () => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = accounts.length > 0;
  const handleLoginClick = async () => {
    await instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).catch((err) => console.error('login failed', err));
  };
  const handleLogoutClick = async () => {
    await instance.logout().catch((err) => console.error('logout failed', err));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>SSO login with Azure MSAL Authentication</h1>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <button onClick={handleLogoutClick}>Logout</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLoginClick}>Login</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;

I added the following URL to the Azure AD app's Authentication as a Single-page application:
http://localhost:3000


Output :
The Next.js code ran successfully, as shown below:

I received the following output in the browser and clicked on the Login button:

The system redirected me to select my account for login, and I chose my account:

I entered my account password for login:

After successfully logging in, I clicked on the Logout button to log out:

It redirected me to select my account for logout:

I successfully logged out.


Do we need _app.tsx ? Iam using layout.tsx as wrapper and setting up all MsalProvider  in same configuration. AppRouter was not working when i added _app.tsx. So relying on layout.tsx.

@Seeker If you want can use _app.tsx. I was able to log in using the above complete code, which I share in the answer.

_app.tsx is only used with the Page-router. This question is regarding setting up MSAL with the App-router. You should also be defining msalInstance outside of MyApp as this will remove it from the React lifecycle and prevent it from being re-instantiated.

Thank you for the clarification. Since the question pertains specifically to setting up MSAL with the App-router, I understand that _app.tsx might not directly apply in this context. I see your point in defining msalInstance outside of MyApp to prevent it from being re-instantiated. Placing it outside the component's render lifecycle ensures consistency throughout the application's lifespan.

@Seeker Did you found the solution ? How can we do server side authentication ?

@JagdishPadeliya Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router/78326638#78326638

using MSAL, I was looking

@JagdishPadeliya I had my inital trail with @azure/msal-react for SSO. Seems something off with App Router compatibility. Even its official documentation has use case of page router and no App router. So.,I moved on to next-auth which is simpler and compatible with App router. Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router/78326638#78326638
