Nexauth with NextJS app router requiring to login twice
I'm using nexauth in my project with next app router in Next 14. I send the project to production in vercel, but every time that i woll login, the first login with correct data does not work only refresh the page, after this i login again and it works normally.
Actually im using credentials method to login, ny login endpoint is in an external api
Somebody already faced this issue?
Already tried https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2426#issuecomment-1141406105 but no success. I need to make login normally

Read this article. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router/78326638#78326638
