Next-Auth protected route issue
I am creating a webapp with next.js. I am using next-auth for it. So when user logged out user will not gave permission to access "/","my-list",etc. If user try to access page without authentication it will redirect to "/login". I implemented it but it is not working properly.
Code :
middleware.ts
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/my-list", "/search/:path*"],
};

Navbar:
"use client";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut({ callbackUrl: "/login" });
  };
  return (
    <div className={`navbar ${isScrolled && "bg-black-1"}`}>
      
          <div className="dropdown-menu">
            <Link href="/">Home</Link>
            <Link href="/my-list">My List</Link>
            <a onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</a>
          </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;

I have used signOut from next-auth/react. How the unauthenticated user can still access  "/", "/my-list", "/search/:path*" and not redirecting to "/login"
Need fix asap!
I want to protect the "/", "/my-list", "/search/:path*" routes and redirect to "/login" when there is no user logged in

Follow this article. This will help you with next-auth blockers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router/78326638#78326638
