I am integrating next-auth functionality in my Next.js app and it throws an error: Catch-all must be the last part of the URL
When I am integrating next-auth functionality in my Next.js application, it throws an error: Catch-all must be the last part of the URL.
I am following the tutorial: https://judy-webdecoded.medium.com/how-i-integrated-authentication-next-auth-v5-in-my-nextjs-14-application-0d57f84cf4ac
I am creating a route.js file in the following location: \pages\api\auth[...nextauth]\route.js
Immediately it throws the above-mentioned error. Also, the application stops with a message in the browser: Internal Server Error.
My package.json file is as follows:
...
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookies-next": "^4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.0",
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.18",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^7.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
...
...```

Can anyone please help?


https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/nextjs-error-catch-all-must-be-the-last-part-of-the-url/23626/2 perhaps?

@CBroe, there is no someDirectory inside my folder. Only one file: route.js

Read this... it has step by step configuration with next-auth and App routet..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78319443/how-to-do-azure-single-sign-on-with-next-js-14-and-app-router

@sabarinath Thank you for the reply. I have found that the issue is when I implement the next-auth in an existing app. When I create a new app, it is working fine.

I found the answer here, remove sub-folders in [...nextauth] folder


thank you for your answer. But there are no subfolders under [...nextauth] folder in my application

that one worked for me :D

I had the same issue because my  "api/[...nextauth]/route.ts" was on the wrong folder for nextjs 15

The issue arises because Next.js expects catch-all segments to be placed in their own folder and to be the last part of the URL. To resolve this, try restructuring your folder like this:
app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

this should fix the issue.
